# Average between timestamps

Tags: google-sheets

Im trying to make myself a formula to be able to analyse my data in a better way.
I have temperature data from 1 hour, measured every second. Now i want to be able to get the average temperatuur between the timestamps I wrote down.

For example, I measured temperature data between 9:00 and 10:00. and want the average temperature between 9:00 and 9:02.

I wrote this formula with the help of an old excel sheet who did the same, but its not working so far
`=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(Average(data!M:M(data!E:E)*(data!E:E>=C3)*(data!E:E<D3))))`

In this formula:

- data is the data tab
- M column is the temperature
- E are the timestamps in the data tab
- C3 - D3 the 2 timestamps (start and stop) where i want to get the average data from

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=average(filter(M:M,(E:E>=C3)*(E:E<=D3)))
```

Result:

[image]

Adapt sheet names as needed.